# Accuracy of TensorFlow model changes a lot each time i run model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My project is to try and find out if I can predict gender of people speaking near phone from data from gyroscope and accelerometer. I have 315 examples(60sec each) and each example has 2997 lines where each line represents magnitude of vector from gyro/accelerometer xyz axis.

I shuffled input and output by same seed and I normalized input data. I split data on 60|20|20. In this test I try from accelerometer to see if there is male speaking, so output is binary.

When I train data with current model, sometimes I get accuracy as high as 0.68 and as low as 0.36 while loss is almost always around 0.69. I run it in a for loop for 10 times and average is 0.5 accuracy and 0.69 loss.

First question is i tried multiple types of models, learning rates, optimization algorithms etc. but in average i wasnt too successful. Should I try Recurrent NNs and where can i learn it?

Second question is if i train model with accuracy of 68%, is it okay to say the model has 68% accuracy even though i know average is 50%?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()    
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu',input_shape = (2997,), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
for j in range(10) :
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.InverseTimeDecay(
  0.001,
  decay_steps=200,
  decay_rate=1,
  staircase=True)    

callbacks = [
             tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
                 monitor='val_loss', patience = 20
             )
]

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate = lr_schedule), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_vector_examples,
    train_vector_labels,
    validation_split = 0.25,
    epochs =80,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    verbose=0,
    shuffle=False
    )    

loss1, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_vector_examples, test_vector_labels)
```

Comment: "Second question is if i train model with accuracy of 68%, is it okay to say the model has 68% accuracy even though i know average is 50%?" Would it be okay to say your salary is 4k when you know the average is 3k? It makes no sense to do that, does it?

Comment: But it isnt great analogy. If model on output says it has 68% accuracy it means it should have that accuracy based on val and test set. In next iteration it can randomize weights differently and get different accuracy. After i fit model its standalone unlike in "salary" analogy.

Answer (score 0):

This is from my own experience working with different types of data; to have get good solutions to your questions you should probably study the characteristics of the data closely before coming up with any models/algorithms.

- First question: generally speaking, RNNs are good for data that has time dependency, or in other words, for cases where the inputs' order matters (e.g. time series, text). So I think RNNs may not be the best choice for your type of data, as I suppose ordering does not matter in your dataset.
- Second question: this really depends on the difficulty of the problem you are trying to solve; but in my opinion 68% is quite low as 50% is basically the same as random choice. You probably want to improve the accuracy further.

Also, from your explanations, I can see that each gyro/accelerometer input has shape of rank 3 (xyz), so maybe you can try some CNN architectures and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am quite a newbie as I studied Deep Learning only theoretically so far. Can you explain few things. How can i study characteristics of the data and what can I find out from that?
As for RNN, my data has time dependecy. Its 60s recorded gyroscope data on 50Hz (therefore 2997 lines, 50 lines per second). Shouldnt RNN preform better as it can maybe detect patterns (few numbers in a row)?
As for second question, I know i should improve accuracy but I was wondering should I fit my model (lets say 10 times) and average it and use that value or best model.fit() value I got?

Comment: Regarding RNN, I misunderstood your dataset; since your data has time dependency RNN (e.g. LSTM) may work well as it's known to be quite good at handling long term dependency. I think your current model.fit() strategy based on converged loss is correct as long as you split your dataset cleanly into different training/validation/testing sets.

Comment: By data analysis I mean things like checking your class balance (whether there are similar number of data for each class/label), maybe some smoothing / noise reduction depending on how the data was taken, maybe even some anomaly detection and removal if necessary. But also be careful that some of these changes to the dataset may create overfitting problems, so it's really up to your experience and experiments with the data. Sometimes even plotting the data in different ways can give you good insights on the dataset.

Comment: As for splitting data, as I said above i have 60% train, 20% val and 20% test sets. For RNN i tried couple of models but no luck. I dont have much knowledge in RNN as I learnt it only for this case. I tried looking for similar cases but most cases are for predicting next value.

Comment: About data analysis I tried as much as possible to give each class equal share of data. I didnt try smoothing/noise reduction as i am not sure how would that work on my dataset. Overfitting usually wasnt the issue as I think its underfitting problem and that what i want is too complicated for classic Deep NN to learn while not having enough knowledge about RNN to customize for my problem.